# SQL query long execute (count in nested select)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have such a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type, (SELECT count(*) FROM ads WHERE ad_type = description_table.type)  
as count FROM description_table;
```

It takes for about 5 minutes to execute. What can be the problem here?

EDIT: Changed the table name from 'desc' to 'description_table' to avoid complication.

Comment: Is `desc` the name of your table?

Comment: You can write particular column name which you want to count instead of count(*)...and what is desc? Is it function or table?

Comment: @RahulTripathi yes, desc is the name of my table

Comment: @eatmypants:- If possible then try to change that as desc is a reserved keyword and it is not recommended to use keywords as table names.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Sorry, forgot about that. It is not the real name of my table, just for simplicity was provided here as 'desc'. Changed it.

Comment: @eatmypants:- Also it would be beneficial to know what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RahulTripathi quickness of course. It is not possibly to execute query for 5 minutes. There must be no complexity in this query, but execution takes much time.

Comment: @eatmypants:- No I am asking in terms of query. Are you trying to find the list of distinct types from your table along with their count?

Comment: @RahulTripathi yes, i need to know count of ads by type

Comment: @eatmypants:- Updated my answer. Check if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your table description_table with ads table. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type, (SELECT count(ads.type) FROM ads join description_table on ads.type = description_table.type)  
as count FROM `description_table`;
```

and instead of counting *, try to count some column like id or type

**EDIT:**

As per your comment you can try this query:

```
SELECT a.type, count(d.type) as count 
FROM description_table d left join ads a on d.type = a.type
group by d.type;
```

Comment: Not sure how well MySQL will handle this. Try alternatively get a distinct list of the Types, and then count(Ads) for that type in a sub-select - using WHERE not JOIN.... In SQL Server I'd use a cross apply

Comment: @RahulTripathi The edited answer returns d.type * ads.type in count column.

Comment: I meant something like this:     SELECT A.Type, (SELECT COUNT(Ad.ID) FROM Ads where Ads.Desc = A.Desc) Count_Ads 
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM DESC 
      ) A